# For bounded $f,g: [0,1]\to\mathbb R$, prove that $\Vert fg\Vert\leq\Vert f\Vert \Vert g\Vert$

Tags: real-analysis

I’m stuck on how to show this property of supnorms. Do you prove it in a similar way to the addition property?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: ||f|| = sup (|f(x)|: x in [0,1])

Comment: Were we supposed to have guessed that?

Comment: In her defense, OP *did* say "supnorms".

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be any (non-empty) set, and let $f \colon S \to \mathbb{C}$ and $g \colon S \to \mathbb{C}$ be any bounded functions. Then by definition
$$
\lVert f \rVert = \sup_{s \in S} \lvert f(s) \rvert,
$$
and similarly for $\lVert g \rVert$.

We note that, for any $s \in S$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\big\lvert \big(fg \big)(s) \big\rvert &= \big\lvert f(s) g(s) \big\rvert \\
&= \big\lvert f(s) \big\rvert \times \big\lvert g(s) \big\rvert \\
&\leq \lVert f \rVert \times \big\lvert g(s) \big\rvert \\
&\leq \lVert f \rVert \times \lVert g \rVert,
\end{align}
$$
and hence 
$$
\lVert fg \rVert = \sup_{s \in S} \big\lvert \big( fg \big)(s) \big\rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert \times \lVert g \rVert,
$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what proof of the "addition property" you're referring to, but here's a proof that I find intuitive.  We have 
$$
\begin{align}
\|fg\| &= \sup \{|f(x)| \cdot |g(x)| : x \in [0,1]\} \\
\\ & \leq 
\sup \{|f(x)| \cdot |g(y)| : x,y \in [0,1]\}\\
\\ & = \left[\sup \{|f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}\right]
\cdot \left[\sup \{|g(y)| : y \in [0,1]\}\right]
\\ & = \|f\| \cdot \|g\|.
\end{align}
$$
The inequality above uses the fact that if $S_1 \subseteq S_2$, then $\sup S_1 \leq \sup S_2$.